# Blotter R used with XTS package

Tags: r, xts

Hi all has anyone noticed that since the last update on 15 Sep blotter R package is not possible to download anymore from the Forge.

Is this a glitch or the whole package has been taken down and is not anymore part of open source?

Answer (score 1):

It is still there and can be downloaded, but not installed:

```
....
* installing *source* package ‘FinancialInstrument’ ...
** R
** data
** demo
** preparing package for lazy loading
Loading required package: Defaults
Loading required package: xts
Loading required package: zoo
Loading required package: TTR
Error : object ‘as.Date’ is not exported by 'namespace:zoo'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘FinancialInstrument’
* removing ‘/home/gavin/R/libs/FinancialInstrument’
ERROR: dependency ‘FinancialInstrument’ is not available for package ‘blotter’
* removing ‘/home/gavin/R/libs/blotter’

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpKtHp8W/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("blotter", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org",  :
  installation of package 'FinancialInstrument' had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("blotter", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org",  :
  installation of package 'blotter' had non-zero exit status
```

There seems to be a problem with building a package (**FinancialInstrument**) which is a dependency for **blotter** and thus things might not be working properlyin the R-Forge build system. Contact the maintainers via the R-Forge site for further help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install FinancialInstrument.  If you already have FinancialInstrument installed, you need to update it, as blotter now Depends on FinancialInstrument(>=0.6.3).